# How to import contact details from MSN, yahoo, gmail, aol in asp.net?

Tags: import, contacts

I am having difficult time in importing contact details from MSN/YAHOO/AOL/GMAIL etc. Can someone tell me how to get the contacts from these networks?

Comment: Can you tell us what you've tried yourself, and what technologies you're using?

Comment: I am using asp.net 3.5. I want to get contact details, as Name and emails for product promotion. User will select his provider as yahoo/msn/gmail/aol and enter his id and password. Then I want to fetch the contacts stored in these providers.

Answer (score 3):

[Yahoo Address Book API](http://developer.yahoo.com/addressbook/)

[Google Contacts API](http://code.google.com/apis/contacts/)

[Windows Live Contacts API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb463974.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for these. Is there anyway to get AOL contact list, by any API's?

Answer (score 1):

One of the ways is to use the open source library [SocialAuth.net](http://code.google.com/p/socialauth.net)

It allows you to get contacts from all the three above, with a very simple API.

Answer (score 1):

CloudSponge.com is a platform that gives you access to these sources and more in a single integration. We use OAuth's 3-legged authentication for services that support it so your users never give their password away. And we have tools to make it easy to integrate; use our widget and get up and running in minutes or use our API and customize every pixel of the user experience.

http://www.cloudsponge.com/developer/